# Git Error: The filename or extension is too long in Kate editor

Tags: windows, git, editor, kate, long-filenames

I have recently switched to Kate due to Atom being discontinued. However I'm having trouble with the Git integration in Kate. I cannot seem to stage all files when I have a lot of files to stage. When I right click on modified and select "Stage All" I receive the following error: "Git Info Process failed to start: The filename or extension is too long."

If I use Git Bash to stage the exact same files using the command `git add *` it works perfectly. No errors. So this issue is related to the Kate Git GUI.

I have searched for answers and I found that because I am on Windows I should set longpaths = true in the git config file. I have done this using this command `git config --system core.longpaths true` and checked the config file and it does now say `longpaths = true` however still the same error is appearing in Kate. Still I cannot stage all in Kate.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks.